# How can I change the True/False questions for the Drupal Quiz Module to Yes/No

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

The Quiz Contributed Module in Drupal provides functionality to ask true/false questions but not yes/no. Is there a way I can extend this module to accomplish this?

Comment: You could possibly change the relevant parts of the language file for that module. But this is neither update friendly, nor does it allow any true false questions in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to enter into code in module file then I would suggest you to use [String Override](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module for replacing true/false with Yes/No. I hope it works...Good Luck..

Answer (score 0):

I checked the quiz module page and it does not mention about any API or similar. So I believe, there is no way for now to achieve that unless you modify the module!